# Motion blur light streak effect looks angular and jagged

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, system

[image]

Trying to get a smooth motion blur effect for some particle lighting systems I am playing around with. However, when looking at the rendering, the streaks of lights are all jagged and angular, they do not follow the smooth curvy path the particles take when I play the animation and looking through the viewport. I feel like this is probably a simply answer/solution but I cannot figure it out. Thank you for the help!

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming the motion vectors are rather... idk how to say this, chunky?  Perhaps adding more time steps to the simulation would solve it

Comment: I guess the only other idea that stands out to me would be to simulate a higher framerate and render every other frame